# How to verify error message displayed in page using selenium webdriver-Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am using this code to verify if error message is present in page.

```
field_required = driver.findElements(
    By.xpath("//*[@id='tab1']/fieldset/div/div/*[text()='This field is required']")
);
```

and checking if `field_required.size() > 0`

The error message should appear only if I leave a field blank and click submit. I noticed that even before I click submit `field_required.size()` is greater than zero .

Hence am guessing that my validation is not done by this code. Please give me another way that would work. Not sure why I am getting incorrect results here.

Comment: Check if your field validations is done by javascript with the onblur event.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like element is already present in the DOM and invisible to end user.

Would you please modify your code as below and try?

```
field_required.size() && field_required.isDisplayed()
```

Here is the link for [isDisplayed](http://static.javadoc.io/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.50.1/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#isDisplayed--)  method